# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined on React-Native expo react-navigation 5.xx

Tags: react-native, components, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-v5

If somebody can help me.
I'm sure that I miss something, but I can't see it.I'm trying to do navigation between 3 components and I create it with the documentation from the react-navigation page, I try a lot of different ways to do it, but always receive the same answer, so if somebody can see the mistake I do please tell me.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './app/components/header/header'
import Main from './app/components/main/main';

import Data from './app/components/data/data';
import Grafic from './app/components/grafic/grafic';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import ButtonImage from './app/components/buttonImag/buttonImg'
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MainScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <ButtonImage onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Main')} heightV={40} widthV={40} itemImage={require('./app/resourse/home.png')} heightI={33} widthI={33} ></ButtonImage>
    );
};
function DataScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <ButtonImage onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Data')} heightV={40} widthV={40} itemImage={require('./app/resourse/datalist.png')} heightI={33} widthI={33} ></ButtonImage>
    );
};
function GraficScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <ButtonImage onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Grafic')} heightV={40} widthV={40} itemImage={require('./app/resourse/grafic.png')} heightI={33} widthI={33} ></ButtonImage>
    );
};

const Footer = ({ navigation }) => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <View style={styles.buttonPos}>
                <MainScreen />
                <DataScreen />
                <GraficScreen />
            </View>
        </View>
    )

};

function MyStack() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={() => <Main />} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Data" component={() => <Data />} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Grafic" component={() => <Grafic />} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

const App = () => {


    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Header />

            <NavigationContainer>
                <MyStack />
            </NavigationContainer>
            <Footer />
        </View>
    );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    header: {

        backgroundColor: "#00BFFF",
        height: 55

    },

    buttonPos: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        padding: 7

    },

    conection: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        padding: 7
    }



});

export default App
```

Comment: Welcome, @Maksym Paranchych to StackOverflow, I would suggest you have your code in next line after ` ` `  . Also, It would be great if you mention your code language with ` ` `.  (It should be without space). It will highlight your keywords. Happy contributing on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do that is to use a Tab Navigator.
react-navigation v5 has 3 ways to do so:

createBottomTabNavigator

createMaterialBottomTabNavigator (very easy to customize)

createMaterialTopTabNavigator (with tabBarPosition: 'bottom')

Also you can customize the tabs by reading the documentation.

I made you a basic example using this last option:

```
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

const Header = () => <View style={styles.header}><Text>Header title</Text></View>
const Main = () => <View style={styles.component}><Text>Main component</Text></View>
const Data = () => <View style={styles.component}><Text>Data component</Text></View>
const Grafic = () => <View style={styles.component}><Text>Grafic component</Text></View>

const footerConfig = {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
}

const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator()

const MyFooter = () => (
    <Tabs.Navigator {...footerConfig}>
        <Tabs.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
        <Tabs.Screen name="Data" component={Data} />
        <Tabs.Screen name="Grafic" component={Grafic} />
    </Tabs.Navigator>
)

const stackConfig = {
    headerMode: 'none',
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

const MyStack = () => (
    <Stack.Navigator {...stackConfig}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={MyFooter} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
)

export default () => (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.main}>

        <Header />

        <NavigationContainer>
            <MyStack />
        </NavigationContainer>

    </SafeAreaView>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    main: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    header: {
        height: 64,
        width: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    component: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
})
```

**EDIT**:

You can use useNavigation hook inside your components. If you want to use your current configuration.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/[useNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/)

Also in order to send navigation props to components this:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Main" component={() => <Main />} />
```

should become:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
// or 
<Stack.Screen name="Main" component={props => <Main {...props} />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to you Main, Data, Grafic components and add {navigation} as your function parameter:

```
function Main({navigation}){
 // rest of your codes

}
export default Main
```